# Is there a way to run saved bigquery in RStudio directly using the link?

Tags: r, google-bigquery

I have a query saved on BigQuery and I wish to find a way to run it directly on RStudio without copy-pasting it. Is there a way where I can use the link of the saved query to tun it in RStudio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For now, `Saved queries` is only accessible through BigQuery UI. There is no way to access it by any API or by code. You can follow feature request at issuetracker https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/111961970

Hope it helps.